# relativenumber stuck on in MacVim

Tags: vim, macvim

Some time ago I experimented with the `relativenumber` setting.  It almost never turned on, so I finally gave up and took it out of my .vimrc.  Now it seems that every time I open up a new instance, I start out in `relativenumber` mode, and my `.vimrc` settings have no effect.  Where is MacVim storing this setting and how can I change it?

Comment: Post your vimrc... and gvimrc

Comment: Also did you really mean to type `.virmrc` settings? Its `.vimrc`

Comment: Your settings are supposed to be in `~/.vimrc`, is that the correct file? Also, do you use sessions? Tinkering and using sessions can create all sorts of confusing issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MacVim will check two main locations for settings. `~/.vimrc` and `~/.gvmirc` make sure

```
set relativenumber
```

and

```
set rnu
```

are not in either of these files.

Also vimrc is sourced before gvimrc so settings in gvimrc will override settings in your vimrc.

Answer (score 0):

The setting was in my forgotten `.gvimrc`.

Comment: even though this is you own question, make your answer more descriptive to help others who might face similar situations